# Azure API Management Premium - do we really need a backup strategy

Tags: azure-api-management

If we use Azure API management **premium** do we need to create a backup (disaster recovery) strategy?

It is replicated in as many separate regions as you want.

In the past, with non-premium we have called the API Management REST API to backup to Azure blog storage.

Obviously, you should always have a DR strategy but just wondering if it is overkill in this scenario.

Comment: I have the same question - one point I can see: if you need to make a point in time recovery to a certain configuration of APIs / Products / Groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure ApiManagement offers SLA on Proxy/Gateway uptime, so if you have a API Management deployed in multiple regions, the Proxy will continue to run, automatically failing over to non affected regions.

However the Publisher Portal, Developer Portal and Management REST Endpoint is still only hosted in the Master Region. If there a region wide disaster in the Master region of your service, they will not be accessible. Which would mean you cannot add new API/operations and new customers cannot subscribe for your service.

If one of the additional regions is impacted, the Proxy/Gateway it will sync up to latest configuration before starting up.

Comment: thanks for this. Answer is great. My question was also relating to disaster recovery so would you say that continuously backing up to Zone Redundant Blob Storage (ZRS) should also be part of the solution? This way, if the master goes down for a long enough time, we can do a point in time restore from blob storage to a new MASTER somewhere. After you comment on my comment I will mark you answer. thanks Russ

Comment: Yes, having a backup will help, if the Master region is down for long enough time. You can work on bringing the other region up, without degradation to the calls coming to your Gateway.